# Real time data Rails- socket

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, websocket, real-time

since rails 5 will be shipped with action cable for real time data transmission, I'm curious to know more about web sockets in ruby.

I never worked with socket in ruby but I know that rails 4+ shipped with ActionLive for real time data use case.

but people are using pusher-app for real time data with rails...

could anyone give some brief idea about ActionLive vs Pusher vs upcoming ActionCable ? why pusher better then actionlive? and how we can take advantage from that?

Comment: notice that Push and Websockets are different - although Push can be implemented using Websockets, that is not the case for most mobile applications where push is used to push notifications even while the app is offline (which invokes a request from the App to the server, creating a connection and pulling data).

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge to answer your question, but I am using Sync in Rails 4.2. Works great! :) I also set up a sample Rails application using Sync and Wiselinks in case you or other viewers may be interested -> https://github.com/jrpolidario/rails_example_with_sync_and_wiselinks